# Criar um botão para registar na base de dados em cada um dos dias

Tags: html

Estou a criar a minha tabela desta forma:

```
<div id="spoiler8" class="esconde">
<table class="table table-responsive" id="employee_table8"> 
<h1 style="font-size: 30px"><strong>Oratório</strong></h1>
<thead>  
<tr> 
<th>Data</th>
<th>Utente</th>
<th>Presença</th>           
<th>Motivo</th> 
<th>Colaborador</th>
<th>Tratamento</th> 
<th>Estado</th>                                 
</tr> 
<tr>
<?php 
do{
if($nomede != $produto8["DataEntrada"]){
?>  
<th style="background-color: #005dab; color: #fff; font-size: 8px;">Data: <?php echo $produto8["DataEntrada"]; ?></th>
<?php
$nomede = $produto8["DataEntrada"];
}
?>
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr> 
<td><?php echo $produto8["DataEntrada"]; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $produto8["nome1"]; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $produto8["Discricao"]; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $produto8["Observacao4"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $produto8["nome"]; ?></td> 
<td><textarea rows="4" id="Notas" name="Notas" value="<?php echo $produto8["Notas"]; ?>"></textarea></td>
<td><select class="form-control" id="EstadoFinal" name="EstadoFinal"><?php echo $produto8["EstadoFinal"]; ?><option value=<?php echo $ln['Id']; ?>><?php echo $ln['Estado']; ?></option>
<?php        
$sql = "SELECT * FROM raddb.Status WHERE Id IN ('8') ORDER BY Estado ASC";
$qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
echo '<option value="'.$ln['Id'].'">'.$ln['Estado'].'</option>';
}
?>      
</select></td> 
</tr> 
<tr>
</tr> 
<?php } while($produto8 = $result8->fetch_assoc()); ?> 
</tbody>  
</table>
</div>
```

Que retorna a tabela desta forma, separada por dias:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pretendo criar um botão para inserir na base de dados também por dia, como mostro na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu dei uma limpada no código PHP só para a tabela renderizar bem no HTML, mas basicamente depois da `th` da data vc precisa de outra `th`, esse por sua vez deve ter um `colspan` de `6`, para "ocupar" todo o espaço restante já que são 7 colunas, e para alinha o btn na direita vc usa o `text-align:righ`. Tb coloquei uma borda nas `th`, `td`, só para ficar melhor de visualisar.

Seu PHP ficaria assim

```
<tr>
    <?php 
    do{
    if($nomede != $produto8["DataEntrada"]){
    ?>  
    <th style="background-color: #005dab; color: #fff; font-size: 8px;">Data: <?php echo $produto8["DataEntrada"]; ?></th>
    <th colspan="6" style="text-align: right"><button>Gravar</button></th>
    <?php
    $nomede = $produto8["DataEntrada"];
    }
    ?>
</tr>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código completo da imagem acima

```css
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="spoiler8" class="esconde">
    <table class="table table-responsive" id="employee_table8">
        <h1 style="font-size: 30px"><strong>Oratório</strong></h1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Utente</th>
                <th>Presença</th>
                <th>Motivo</th>
                <th>Colaborador</th>
                <th>Tratamento</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="background-color: #005dab; color: #fff; font-size: 18px;">Data: <?php echo $produto8["DataEntrada"]; ?></th>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align: right"><button>Gravar</button></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $produto8["DataEntrada"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $produto8["nome1"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $produto8["Discricao"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $produto8["Observacao4"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $produto8["nome"]; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea rows="4" id="Notas" name="Notas" value="<?php echo $produto8["Notas"]; ?>"></textarea>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" id="EstadoFinal" name="EstadoFinal">
                    <option value=<?php echo $ln['Id']; ?>><?php echo $ln['Estado']; ?></option>
                    <option value="'.$ln['Id'].'">'.$ln['Estado'].'</option></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```